# How to delete cases in PM?

Tags: processmaker-api

I am trying to delete cases in PM but I am not able to using the API

[http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.1/REST_API_Cases#Delete_Case:*DELETE*.2Fcases.2F.7Bapp_uid.7D](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.1/REST_API_Cases#Delete_Case:_DELETE_.2Fcases.2F.7Bapp_uid.7D)

I have tried this API but it gives me an error like:

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException]                                                                                                                  
  Client error: `DELETE http://processmaker.app:32768/api/1.0/workflow/cases/50492041658e1dfca544ad3002222462` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:  
  {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Bad Request: You can't delete the case because it's not in Draft status and was already  (truncated...)
```

Yes, I even tried cancelling the case but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is because you cannot delete a case once it has left the status of DRAFT. That means, once a case is submitted to the next task, it is considered in the status of TODO.

So, once a case has transitioned to the status of TODO, you may only Cancel a case, not delete it.

You can find more information relating to that here: http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.1/user_guide#Cancel

Don't forget to make sure that the user you are making the rest api call as has the right permissions to be able to cancel/delete the case as well.

To cancel a case through the rest api, take a look at this link: [http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.1/REST_API_Cases#Cancel_Case:*PUT*.2Fcases.2F.7Bapp_uid.7D.2Fcancel](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.1/REST_API_Cases#Cancel_Case:_PUT_.2Fcases.2F.7Bapp_uid.7D.2Fcancel)

I hope that helps!